# Growl-WithInstaller.framework keep failing on Xcode4

Tags: xcode, growl

These are my steps

I downloaded the latest Growl sdk and put the Growl-WithInstaller.framework in the /Frameworks folder.

1. Drag & drop Grow-WithInstaller.framework directory to "Framework" in project, Copy Items into destination folder...
2. I see Growl-WithInstaller.framework in "Summary" -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries, marked as Required
3. Then created a new build phrase, Copy Files. Drag Growl-WithInstaller.framework from the left side of the Project navigator to it the column row. Set Destination to Frameworks and also set Copy Only when installing.

Then I keep getting this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Growl-WithInstaller.framework/Versions/A/Growl-WithInstaller
  Referenced from:...  Reason: image not found
```

Did I missed any steps? Of course if I copy the Growl-WithInstaller.framework to /Libararies/Frameworks, then everything works fine, but if I try to run the app in a Mac with the framework in the /Lib, then it will break.

Help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uncheck "Copy only when installing" so it doesn't only copy when installing.

Comment: Does this mean it will copy everytime?

Comment: Yes, which is what you want. It needs to be part of the bundle for you to even run it as a debug build, so it should be copied every time the app bundle is built. Of course Xcode is (usually) smart enough to know when it actually has to copy it (ie, if it hasn't changed and it's already in the bundle, don't bother).